# Hand a Laravel Model to Vue.js Component with more than one JSON "Deep Level"

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

### This is my View-Blade.php:

```
<comment-component :comments="{{$offer->comments}}" ></comment-component>
```

### this is my Vue-Component:

```
export default {
  props:['comments'],
  ...
}
```

**Problem**:

My Laravel Comment-Model has a one to many relation with Employee-Model, so if i hand over the Comment-Models to the Vue-Component, it will hand over as a JSON with only 1 "Deep-Level".

So The Comment-Json Object has just the employee_id and not the employee-Json-Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<comment-component :comments="{{$offer->load('comments.employee')}}" ></comment-component>
```